# How to get a good dendrogram using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, ggdendro

I am using R to do a hierarchical cluster analysis using the Ward's squared euclidean distance. I have a matrix of x columns(stations) and y rows(numbers in float), the first row contain the header(stations' names). I want to have a good dendrogram where the name of the station appear at the bottom of the tree as i am not able to interprete my result. My aim is to find those stations which are similar.  However using the following codes i am having numbers (100,101,102,...) for the lower branches.

```
Yu<-read.table("yu_s.txt",header = T, dec=",")
library(cluster)
agn1 <- agnes(Yu, metric = "euclidean", method="ward", stand = TRUE)
hcd<-as.dendrogram(agn1)

par(mfrow=c(3,1))

plot(hcd, main="Main")
plot(cut(hcd, h=25)$upper, 
     main="Upper tree of cut at h=25")
plot(cut(hcd, h=25)$lower[[2]], 
     main="Second branch of lower tree with cut at h=25")
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice collection of examples are present here (http://gastonsanchez.com/blog/how-to/2012/10/03/Dendrograms.html)

Two methods:

with `hclust` from base `R`

```
hc<-hclust(dist(mtcars),method="ward")
plot(hc)
```

**Default plot**

[image]

**ggplot**

with `ggplot` and `ggdendro`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)

# basic option
ggdendrogram(hc, rotate = TRUE, size = 4, theme_dendro = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: +1 For nice examples as well as for an easy to interpret, useful example of how to rotate a dendrogram (flip dendrogram 90 degrees). Adding this comment so that it is easier to find with Google.